# remove http from URL in .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Been stuck on this for ages and tried loads of fixes but just can't get my head around it!

I run a site where the content of the pages are generated based upon a URL. For example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/http://www.supercheese.com
```

Would generate a mashup of content from mysite.com and supercheese.com

The .htaccess i use for this (at mysite.com) is:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteRule assets/.* - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$  test.php?url=$1 [NC,L]

</ifModule>
```

So basically the second URL is passed in a php string.

My question is this, I need to remove the http:// from the address using .htaccess

E.G. If someone types:

```
http://www.mysite.com/http://www.supercheese.com
```

I need it to become:

```
http://www.mysite.com/www.supercheese.com
```

Many thanks in advance for taking a look at this. You guys rock.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `RedirectMatch`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Try with :

```
RedirectMatch ^/https?://(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1
```

Edit : you have to put this before rewrite rules

Edit : add `/` before http

Edit : David is right, take a look a his answer and change your way of writing these urls

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Tried putting it at the end but no luck :(

Comment: you have to put this RedirectMatch before rewrite rules

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. That didn't seem to work. The redirect didn't happen. I put it before rewrite rules as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the url scheme is inherently problematic.

Using an unencoded colon `:` in the url - other than following the `http` to specify the access protocol - seems to make the server think that it is doing authentication of the form `http://username:password@hostname/`.

I know it doesn't directly answer the question, the solution is to change the url-scheme. ;-(

Comment: I remember having problems to rewrite URLs containing a scheme in the path. I guess the ":" should be URL encoded to %3a

Comment: @Capsule, @soju: Indeed. The upshot is that including the `http://` inside the url is going to be problematic. Best to strip all that out.

Comment: No need to "hide" the problematic characters, just url-encode them.